# Is there any way that i can read multiple different file type like xlsv, csv, xls in Google drive using pydrive?

Tags: python, excel, google-drive-api, spreadsheet, pydrive

So I want to create a condition that allows me to read two or more file types in google drive using pydrive. But I don't know where to start.

and I do have this code.

```
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()

 spreadsheet_id = '######'

    #This is to read spreadsheet file
    url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + spreadsheet_id + "/export?mimeType=application%2Fvnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    res = requests.get(url, headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + gauth.attr['credentials'].access_token})

    #This is to read xlsv
    url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + spreadsheet_id + "?alt=media"
    res = requests.get(url, headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + gauth.attr['credentials'].access_token})

    # 2. The downloaded XLSX data is read with `pd.read_excel`.
    sheet = "Summary"

    values = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(res.content), usecols=None, sheet_name=sheet)
    print (values)


    return ''
```

Answer (score 0):

### You cannot read those files directly with the Drive or Sheets API, but you can convert them to Google spreadsheets

Use the method [Files: insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert)  for Dirve v2 or [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)  for v3.

With pydrive it should look like this:

```py
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
file = drive.CreateFile({
                        ,'title': 'myNewGoogleSpreadsheet'
                        ,'mimeType':'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'})
file.SetContentFile('myExcelFile')
file.Upload({'convert': True})
```

**References:**

- [pyDrive](https://pypi.org/project/PyDrive/)
- [Import to Google Docs types v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/manage-uploads#import_to_google_docs_types)
- [Import to Google Docs types v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#import_to_google_docs_types)